# How to get info pages

Tags: manpage, info

Using info info opens the man page for info. From what I've search there doesn't seem to be anything to download.

How do I get the info pages instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install texinfo-doc-nonfree
```

Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will install the package with the info info documents.